# Find a specific text and cut all the lines below it and paste to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find the word "BREAK" and cut the lines below it until it reaches another word "BREAK" and transfer it to another Sheet.

I need to separate it to 5 sheets since I have 5 word of "BREAK" in the file.

```
Sub Fails()

Dim mFind As Range
Set mFind = Columns("A").Find("BREAK")
If mFind Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "There is no cell found with the text 'BREAK'" _
    & " in column A of the active sheet."
    Exit Sub
End If

firstaddress = mFind.Address

Do
    If IsDate(mFind.Offset(1, 0)) = True Then
        Range(mFind, Cells(mFind.Row + 2, "A")).EntireRow.Cut
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    ElseIf WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(mFind.Offset(1, 0)) = True Then
        Range(mFind, Cells(mFind.Row + 3, "A")).EntireRow.Cut
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Set mFind = Columns("A").FindNext(mFind)
    If mFind Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Loop While mFind.Address <> firstaddress

End Sub
```

Nothing is happening with the code above. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you and have a good day everyone.

Comment: Are your Sheet Called "Sheet1" and "Sheet2" ?

Comment: Yes Sir @Dorian it is called Sheet1 and Sheet2

Comment: In the code you shown your If condition is checking if "Break" Is a date if Yes then it will copy it and paste it to another cell. But "Break" Isn't really a date so the If condition will never work....

Answer (score 0):

Give this code a try, your If statement was false

```
Sub Fails()
Dim mFind As Range
Dim Compteur As Integer
Dim IdSheet As Integer
Dim ErrorBool As Boolean


Set mFind = Columns("A").Find("Break")
Set mfind2 = Columns("A").Find("Break")
If mFind Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "There is no cell found with the text 'Break'" _
    & " in column A of the active sheet."
    Exit Sub
End If

firstaddress = mFind.Address
IdSheet = 1
Compteur = 0
Do

        Set mfind2 = Columns("A").FindNext(mFind)

        If mfind2 Is Nothing Then

        Compteur = Sheet1.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

        'Exit Sub

        Else:
        If mFind.Row < mfind2.Row Then
         Compteur = mfind2.Row
        End If
        If mFind.Row > mfind2.Row Then
         ErrorBool = True
        End If

        If ErrorBool = True Then

        Range(mFind, Cells(mFind.Row + 1, "A")).EntireRow.Cut

        End If
        End If

        Range("A" & mFind.Row + 1 & ":A" & Compteur - 1).EntireRow.Cut

        If mFind Is Nothing Then

        Else: IdSheet = IdSheet + 1

        End If
        Sheets("Sheet" & IdSheet & "").Select
        Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range(mFind, Cells(mFind.Row, "A")).EntireRow.Delete
    Set mFind = Columns("A").Find("Break")
    Set mfind2 = Columns("A").Find("Break")
    If mFind Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set mFind = Columns("A").FindNext(mFind)




Loop While mFind.Address <> firstaddress

End Sub
```

**Note** : You must create Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3, Sheet4 ,Sheet5 and so on before run macro.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. I tried your code and it copies the lines with Breaks only but what I am in need of is to cut the BREAK and the lines below it before another BREAK to another sheet. the next BREAK should be in a different sheet also, so all in all it should have 5 sheets. I really appreciate your help. thank you so much.

Comment: @Zha Just Edited the code this might work, Kindest regard.

Comment: Good day, I have tried your code and there are just one error. The word "break" and all the lines below which comes first was transferred successfully in other sheets but the LAST one wasn't transferred all. The only thing that was transferred was the line of "break" and the first line below it.

Comment: I think only the last part of the code is in need of change. "line:
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range(mFind, Cells(mFind.Row, "A")).EntireRow.Delete
    Set mFind = Columns("A").Find("Break")
    Set mfind2 = Columns("A").Find("Break")
    If mFind Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set mFind = Columns("A").FindNext(mFind)"

Comment: @Zha Try this, it should work, if it don't tell me what are the error you got, I tested it its working

Comment: @ZharinaLorraineMoldez If this issue is solved May I ask you to accept this answer ? Click [here to see how to accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)